# Les segments d'entrevues qui ont été « songifiés », « où on a fait un "songify" » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, formulation

Je dis à quelqu'un que je lui montre deux vidéos ([1](https://youtu.be/9QS0q3mGPGg) [2](https://youtu.be/812fbaau7qQ)) et elle me demande ce que c'est et je lui explique que ce sont des segments d'entrevues qui ont été « *songify* »-iés (je dis *songifiés*, ou « un songify » et là je me dis que je devrais parler dans ma langue). Le verbe n'est pas nécessairement un néologisme accepté [en anglais](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87901/is-songify-a-well-received-word-as-an-english-neology) mais je m'intéresse surtout à exprimer ça en français et évidemment c'est « ...en chanson » mais j'ai eu une hésitation avec mon interlocuteur quant au choix du verbe auxiliaire, ce ne sont pas exactement des paroles écrites alors je me demande si il doit y avoir un complément aussi, et je me suis demandé en même temps si on accepte davantage qu'en anglais un verbe construit sur *chanson* avec un suffixe [*-ifier*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ifier).

Quel auxiliaire on choisit ici ou préfère-t-on faire un verbe de tout ça, et a-t-on besoin d'un complément pour traiter de ce dont il s'agit, ou on dit simplement « chanson » et on explique le procédé de création après mais comment l'introduit-on ?

Answer (score 1):

*Songifiés* ne passe pas, d'autant plus qu'il fait d'abord penser à songe plutôt que l'anglais *song*.

J'aurais probablement dit en premier « des extraits d'interviews qui ont étés mis en musique » mais si j'ai bien compris, il s'agit de plus qu'une mise en musique. On pourra donc pourquoi pas choisir « **chansonifier** » qui est le calque de *songify* et qui a l'aval de l'OQLF.

Réf. : [Politique de l'emprunt linguistique, OQLF](https://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/bibliotheque/terminologie/20170330_politique_emprunt.pdf).

Comment: Merci ! _Songifiés_ non d'acc. J'avais pas pensé regarder au GDT comme en fait je ne trouvais pas le terme dans les dictionnaires anglais. Mais donc c'est « mettre ». Le « plus qu'une mise en musique », donc peut-être qu'il faut un truc comme _remixage_ je sais pas trop. Ils disent _avec un programme informatique_ mais ultimement qui ferait ça sans programme informatique aujourd'hui. Ils ont aussi [-iser](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26520040) et le même doublon en [substantif](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26520041). Je sais pas si c'est bien ficelé.

Comment: *Remixer* ou "c'est un remix".

Comment: Oui, bien un trucmuche que je ne sais pas nommer, je vais dire changement de classe sémantique ou de référentiel, s'impose parfois pour trouver quelque chose de mieux senti ou de plus clair. Le temps dira si les trucs avec les suffixes s'imposent ou si le procédé est digne d'un rayonnement lexical ou je ne sais trop.

Comment: C'est beaucoup plus chantant que « ajustement automatique d'intonation » pour [autotune](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=autotune) .